# What would be the dependency for no.petroware.logio.las.LasFileReader;

Tags: java, logging, las, log-ascii-standard

I am trying to read LAS file using java LasFileReader but I am not getting what would be the maven dependency for this import "import no.petroware.logio.las.LasFileReader;"

Answer (score 0):

From the [official site](https://petroware.no/logio.html):

> Log I/O **is available for Java (LogIo.jar)**...

According to [this](https://github.com/Petroware/LogIo)

> The JSON Well Log Format accessor depends on the JSON API
>   specification and an implementation of this:

So, you need 3 jars, which you can found it [here](https://github.com/Petroware/LogIo/tree/master/lib)

or directly clone the repository

```
git clone https://github.com/Petroware/LogIo.git
```

and the go to

```
./LogIo/lib
```

After that you have to import them to your project (eclipse steps).

1. Right click on your project
2. Select Build Path
3. Click on Configure Build Path
4. Click on Libraries and select Add External JARs
5. Select the 3 jars
6. Click and Apply and Ok

Comment: "las.LasFileReader" is not available in any import

Comment: Did you check if `no` package is available? or even in the classpath?